# Is it possible to use a JavaScript in simple math equation but place results in a div

Tags: javascript, html, equation

I'm trying to put the results of this simple JavaScript into a div, where i put the results anywhere on the  webpage

Example script:

```
var numOne=25
  , numTwo=14
  , res
  ; 
res = numOne - numTwo; 
document.write(" " + res + "");
```

I don't have a clue how to set this up in the script

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Create a div

It is best if it already exists in the HTML and has an id, as shown below.

#### Use `document.getElementById` to access that element, and put the result into its `innerText`

Here is an example.

```js
var numOne = 25,
  numTwo = 14,
  res;
res = numOne - numTwo;

document.getElementById("result").innerText = res;
```

```html
<div id="result"></div>
```

Comment: WHy `innerHTML`? Do you expect this function to ever return valid markup that should be parsed?

Comment: Agreed, changed!